# Why is $this->set not working in cake PHP?

Tags: cakephp

```
$arrData = $this->params['url'];
$this->set('value',$this->params['url']['eslPageIndex']);
pr($value);
```

It throws Error:

> `Undefined variable: value [APP/controllers/esl_controller.php, line 34]`

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->set('value', ...);
```

means there will be a variable named `$value` made available **in the view**. It does not set it in the controller function. Hence `pr($value)` fails because there is no variable `$value` there.

Comment: If you want to see what you are setting the view variable `$value` to, you will need to `pr($this->params['url']['eslPageIndex'])`

Answer (score 0):

^^^ theres your answer! I find it is often better to do like this to avoid your issue:

$myVar = ..something...;

$myVar2 = ...some other expression... ;

$this->set(compact('myVar','myVar2');

more readable and needs only one set call! you can also then use pr() in your controllerto debug